# How to introduce semi-transparent rect in Delphi TCanvas?

Tags: delphi, transparency

I had a source code of a drawing software from somewhere which was written in Delphi 7. The code is pretty code and big. Everything drawing with that software is solid, no transparency. I try to read most of the code and I found that the main component used for drawing is TCanvas. Is there any easy way to setup the TCanvas so that transparency is allowed? Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty general question. Transparency and drawing  is a broad topic. Could you narrow it down a little perhaps?

Comment: You want the existing code to draw its painting transparently? Onto what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparency  is not a Problem fo the canvas, it's a problem of the painting. There is no way to make a wincontrol real transparent except a layered window, if this is your question, but you can paint with transparence on every canvas. E.g.

```
Canvas.Draw(0,0,png1);
Canvas.Draw(0,0,png2);
```

If you want do easy paint with transparency you could use GDI+, can be got from http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7

This would be an example how to draw a transparent selection without aditional librarays

```
unit Unit3;
// 20121108 by Thomas Wassermann
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, jpeg;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FDownPoint, FCurrentPoint: TPoint;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

uses Math;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.BringToFront;
end;

type
  pRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
  TRGBQuadArray = ARRAY [0 .. $EFFFFFF] OF TRGBQuad;

Procedure SetAlpha(bmp: TBitMap; Alpha: Byte; R: TRect);
var
  pscanLine32: pRGBQuadArray;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  bmp.PixelFormat := pf32Bit;
  bmp.HandleType := bmDIB;
  bmp.ignorepalette := true;
  bmp.alphaformat := afDefined;
  for i := 0 to bmp.Height - 1 do
  begin
    pscanLine32 := bmp.Scanline[i];
    for j := 0 to bmp.Width - 1 do
    begin
      if (j >= R.Left) and (j <= R.Right) and (i >= R.Top) and (i <= R.Bottom) then
      begin
        pscanLine32[j].rgbReserved := 0;
        pscanLine32[j].rgbBlue := 0;
        pscanLine32[j].rgbRed := 0;
        pscanLine32[j].rgbGreen := 0;
      end
      else
      begin
        pscanLine32[j].rgbReserved := Alpha;
        pscanLine32[j].rgbBlue := Alpha;
        pscanLine32[j].rgbRed := Alpha;
        pscanLine32[j].rgbGreen := Alpha;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDownPoint.X := X;
  FDownPoint.Y := Y;
  FCurrentPoint := FDownPoint;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm3.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if ssLeft in Shift then
  begin
    FCurrentPoint.X := X;
    FCurrentPoint.Y := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
var
  bmp: TBitMap;
  SelRect: TRect;
begin
  bmp := TBitMap.Create;
  try
    bmp.Width := PaintBox1.Width;
    bmp.Height := PaintBox1.Height;
    if (FCurrentPoint.X = FDownPoint.X) and (FCurrentPoint.Y = FDownPoint.Y) then
      SelRect := PaintBox1.BoundsRect
    else
    begin
      SelRect.Left := Min(FCurrentPoint.X, FDownPoint.X);
      SelRect.Top := Min(FCurrentPoint.Y, FDownPoint.Y);
      SelRect.Right := Max(FCurrentPoint.X, FDownPoint.X);
      SelRect.Bottom := Max(FCurrentPoint.Y, FDownPoint.Y);
    end;
    SetAlpha(bmp, 140, SelRect);
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bmp);
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think I cannot modify the code very much. I know that the container is TCustomControl and the canvas is TCanvas. What I can do is to inherit the TCanvas so the the software will use mine canvas instead. Buy how to do so? I cannot add any components (like PaintBox, BitMap, etc.).

Comment: I don't think this will be possible, Canvas is a readonly Proprty for private FCanvas.